# Submit data to JSON/API URL

Tags: php, json, forms, api

I need to send some Contact Form 7 (WordPress) Data to another platform with JSON API in POST method. I have:

API URL is `ezramod.xyz/users/executeAPIcall`.

Request body:

```
{"apiUsername":"<apiUsername>", "apiPassword":"<apiPassword>", "apicallsetinput":[{"_apicall":"create","firstname":"Test","lastname":"User","password":"qwertyui1!","email":"test@3rdpartydomain.com","company":"3rdparty","title":"Engineer","language":"United States - English","event_id":<eventId>, "entitlement_group":"default group"}]}
```

I try to do in this mode:

```
function on_submit( $form, &$abort, $submission )
{
    if ( $abort === TRUE || $form->ID() !== 999 ) {
        return;
    }

    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    $email = sanitize_text_field($data['email']);
    $firstname = sanitize_text_field($data['firstname']);
    $lastname = sanitize_text_field($data['lastname']);

    
$endpoint = 'ezramod.xyz/users/executeAPIcall';
 
$body = [
    "apiUsername" => "ezramod", 
    "apiPassword" => "password", 
    "apicallsetinput" => array(
    "_apicall"          =>  "create",
    "firstname"         =>  "".$data['firstname']."",
    "lastname"          =>  "".$data['lastname']."",
    "email"             =>  "".$data['email']."",
    "event_id"          =>  274, 
    "entitlement_group" =>  "default group",    
    ),
];  
 
$body = wp_json_encode( $body );
 
$options = [
    'body'        => $body,
    'headers'     => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'timeout'     => 60,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'blocking'    => true,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify'   => false,
    'data_format' => 'body',
];
 
wp_safe_remote_post( $endpoint, $options );
    
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'on_submit', 10, 3);
```

without success, have some idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function on_submit( $form, &$abort, $submission )
{
    if ( $abort === TRUE || $form->ID() !== 13 ) {
        return;
    }

    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    $email = sanitize_text_field($data['email']);
    $firstname = sanitize_text_field($data['firstname']);
    $lastname = sanitize_text_field($data['lastname']);
        
$endpoint = 'https://ezramod.xyz/executeAPIcall';
    
$body = array(
    "apiUsername" => "ezramod", 
    "apiPassword" => "password",
    "apicallsetinput" => array(
        array(
        "_apicall"          =>  "create",
        "firstname"         =>  "".$data['firstname']."",
        "lastname"          =>  "".$data['lastname']."",
        "email"             =>  "".$data['email']."",
        "event_id"          =>  274, 
        "entitlement_group" =>  "default group",
        ),
    ),
);  
    
$args = array(
    'headers'     => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
    'body'        => json_encode($body),
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'data_format' => 'body',
);     
//wp_remote_post( $endpoint, $options ); 
$request_body = wp_safe_remote_post( $endpoint, $args );
 
//$request = new WP_Http;
//$result = $request->request( $endpoint, array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $json_body) );
// test $result['response'] and if OK do something with $result['body']
  if ( is_wp_error( $request_body ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request_body ) != 200 ) {
        //error_log( print_r( $request_body, true ) );
        //error_log( print_r( $json_body, true ) );
    } else {
        //error_log( print_r( $request_body, true ) );
        //error_log( print_r( $json_body, true ) );
    }
    
}
```